# How to access parent object of member object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Suppose I have

```py
class tool:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.name = x

class shed1:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = tool("hammer")
```

Suppose there are three types of shed classes `shed1,shed2,shed3` (different classes). I have a list, for example, `list_of_member_tool_object_references = [SH1.root, SH2a.root, SH2b.root, SH3.root]`. This list references the `tool` member variable of a particular `shed` class where `SH1, SH2(a/b), SH3` are objects of classes `shed1,shed2,shed3`. How do I back track to obtain the `shed` object. For example the answer `answer(list_of_member_tool_object_references)` should return references to `[SH1,SH2a,SH2b,SH3]`

Comment: You don't. There are no back references, unless you implement them. If you want tool to know about shed, then you need to have e.g. `self.shed = shed` in the tool object.

Comment: Separately from your actual question, it looks like you're trying to use inheritance, incorrectly? Otherwise, I'm not sure why `tool` is relevant in your example code

Comment: objects don't have "parents". You say "This list references the tool member variable of a particular shed class where" That isn't what that list has. You cannot reference *variables* in a list (or in Python, generally). You reference *objects*. That your list references an object that happens to be referenced by some other object as an attribute is not known to the object itself, or the list, or the other object. You have to manage these relationships yourself.

Comment: @zvone or better yet, have some other object handle these relationships

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, of course, it would probably be best to change the whole original idea to avoid need for circular references, and to have a cleaner design.